# Update already installed android application gives error "an existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed"

Tags: android

I made an Android application using intellijidea 14. It was great, I made changes in the project and generated and distributed Apk several times in 2014

But Few day ago when I made some changes and rebuild project (I did not use signed apk ever). And try to install apk on device (where I have application installed already), then it gives me error while updating:

> an existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed

I have tried everything, I never generated apk using any signature (never create or used any keystore). I was just using apk generated in Out Folder.

Now I am unable to update my already installed android app. I cannot UNINSTALL it as I have a database which has crucial values (which I can't afford to loose this data). As application is already installed on 15 devices.

I need to update all 15 devices application. How can I make a new apk with old apk signature?

Comment: You could try installing the release-apk from the project folder which is an unsigned version(if I'm not mistaken) of  your apk. you could use adb to install it.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious. You have not signed your new built with older `SHA-1`. mean while your phone installed the older app with `SHA-1`. So built new **apk** with the same `SHA-1`.

[Refer official docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) for that.

Comment: Hey MD
Sorry i am just a novice in android development , how can i do that ? when i goggled it everybody is telling me how to create a keystore or create a signed  apk . but how can i use older signature  in my case ?